# Scrollreveal.js отказывется работать

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, odoo

Преамбула: 
Попросили написать простой одностраничник, без админки. Быстро сверстал на бутстрапе, то что было нужно, и добавил анимацию появления секций (тот самый scrollreveal.js)

Всё замечательно работало примерно вот так.

```
<head>
  <script src="scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="animated">
  </section>
  <section class="animated">
  </section>
  <section class="animated">
  </section>
  <script>
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.animated');
  </script>
</body>
```

Амбула: позже, попросили пересадить эту страничку на ERP Odoo. Вот тут то и начались проблемы - `scrollreveal.js` перестал работать. Точнее перестал работать наполовину. Всем секциям с классом `animated` скриптом проставляется `opacity:0`, но когда секция попадает во вьюпорт, `opacity` секции не становится = 1, т.е. остаётся прозрачным.

Опытным путём выяснил, что онскролл события не работают вообще. Дописал маленький скрипт в код странички:

```
<script>
  window.onscroll = function () {
    console.log('qwe');
  };
</script>
```

Ничего не логгировалось. (Проверил тот же скрипт локально на html стрничке, вдруг где ошибся? Нет, локально лог пишется, онскролл работает).

Куда копать дальше, не знаю. 
Может у вас появятся какие мысли по этому поводу? Заранее спасисбо.

upd. Еще один момент header c абсолютным позиционированием в odoo почему-то ведёт себя как `position:fixed (или stiky)` остаётся приклеен к верху вьюпорта. (Опять же, ведёт себя нормально на простой html страничке). Не знаю есть ли здесь связь с проблемой выше, но может кого натолкнёт на правильную мысль.

upd2. Для того, чтобы odoo схавал страничку, нужно чтобы она была в xml. Код, в котором onscroll не работает выглядит так.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
  <template id="myhomepage" inherit_id="website.homepage">
    <xpath expr="." position="replace">
      <t name="Homepage" priority="29" t-name="website.homepage">
       <!--Дальше всё как в работающем html-->
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
       <!--Ну и закрывающие теги для xml-->
      </t>
    </xpath>
  </template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое ERP Odoo, но по описанию проблемы похоже, что ваша страничка запускается в некотором контейнере. Исследуйте страницу, посмотрите, как там все устроено. Можете даже код страницы скинуть сюда.

Comment: Кстати, да. Совсем забыл добавить. Весь бэкенд odoo на питоне (но это роли наверное не играет). А вот фронтенд на xml сверстан, что может быть важно. Сейчас добавлю код страницы в вопрос.

Comment: А вы посмотрите в DevTools код актуальной странички. Я не думаю, что браузер парсит xml.

Comment: Действительно. В devtools структура обычная ```<html><head></head><body></body></html>```. Но не  объявлен doctype

Comment: Хорошо, в этой обычной структуре где находятся ваши секции? Прямо в body?

Comment: Омг. Спасибо, Вы очень помогли. Когда есть собеседник, всё намного проще. Дело было действительно в doctype. Только объявляется он в этой клятой odoo через одно место. Если интересно, вот так ```&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;```

Comment: Я сравнил буквально построчно в девтулз две разные страницы (рабочую и не очень), благо там строк не много, <100. Всё было идентично, кроме doctype

Comment: И что, после указания `doctype` все заработало?

Comment: Невероятно, но факт. Сам даже бы и не подумал в эту сторону копать, но когда после сравнения двух страниц в devtools никаких отличий кроме этого не нашел, решил попробовать, и "о, чудо", всё заработало. И хеадер отлип, и онскролл события начали обрабатываться.

Comment: Добавлю ответ в вопрос, может еще кому поможет.

Comment: Обязательно сделайте ответ! Это может помочь кому-то в будущем! Только ответ сделайте ответом, не добавляйте ответ в вопрос.

Comment: Так точно! Сделаю, спасибо за подсказку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в потерянном `<!doctype html>`.
Решение которое помогло мне, и возможно, поможет кому-то еще - объявить doctype в самом шаблоне:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
  <template id="myhomepage" inherit_id="website.homepage">
    <xpath expr="." position="replace">
      <t name="Homepage" priority="29" t-name="website.homepage">
        +  <!--declare doctype-->
        +  &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
        +  <!--declare doctype/-->
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
      </t>
    </xpath>
  </template>
</odoo>
```

П.с. Если вы опытный пользователь Odoo, то скорее всего сможете решить проблему правильно, "по-одушному". Я же с Odoo познакомился из необходимости и буквально несколько дней назад. 
Дополню свой ответ, когда найду другое, красивое, решение.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы что-то забыли в вашем новом шаблоне `myhomepage` для Odoo.
К примеру обязателен вызов `<t t-call="website.layout">`